# Amplify SSL cert issued by Amazon not found in ACM?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I inherited an application and AWS infrastructure using a wildcard certificate on Amplify. We're moving away from Amplify and I want to move the certificate to CloudFront, but I can't seem to find the certificate anywhere outside of Amplify. It's not in ACM.

I checked all regions and only one cert in ACM and it's not that one (the one there is for a specific domain, not wildcard).

I assume I'm missing something. In one location in the console Amplify even says the cert is in ACM.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is to create a new certificate using ACM and [set up CloudFront with https](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) as if it was a new domain.

You can have many different different certificates for the same domain with no problems. They don't have to come from the same CA, so long as they're valid certificates.